# Create a function which reads all lines of code from text file and put each line into tuples. -Python 3

Tags: python, function, io, tuples

So far I have this:

```
f = open('studs.txt')

with open('studs.txt') as inputFile:
    tupless = [tuple(line.split()) for line in inputFile.readlines()]
    print(tupless)

The text file format I'm opening is like this:
12345 5 G421 Hello Sir
12345 2 G782 Byeee Sir 

So with this code it prints out something like this:
[('12345', '5', 'G421', 'Hello', 'Sir'), ('12345', '2', 'G782', 'Byeee' ,'Sir']

Now I want an output like this:
['12345','5','G421', 'Hello', 'Sir'] \n
['12345','2','G782', 'Byeee' ,'Sir']
etc.
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
with open("studs.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split())
```